# problem in transforming a for statement into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to transform the below code into list comprehension form :

```
word_list = ["cat","dog","rabbit"]
letter_list = []
for a_word in word_list:
   for a_letter in a_word:
      if a_letter not in letter_list:
        letter_list.append(a_letter)
print(letter_list)
```

And I have done this :

```
word_list = ["cat" , "dog" , "rabbit"]
letter_list = []
letter_list = [a_letter for a_word in word_list for a_letter in a_word if a_letter not in letter_list]
print(letter_list)
```

but the output shows the duplicates which I do not want. What  should I do ?

Comment: You can't convert that loop to a list comprehension because it uses information from the partially constructed `letter_list` to decide whether or not to append a new element to `letter_list`. In the list comprehension, you do not have access to the list being built. If you want to convert it to a list comprehension because you believe it will be faster -- it won't.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you don't need to keep the order, your problem is better solved by a set:

```
word_list = ["cat","dog","rabbit"]
letter_set = {letter for word in word_list for letter in word}
```

Sets guarantee uniqueness of elements, which is what you want (assuming I understood your question). This uses the comprehension style, but you could also unwrap this into the nested for loops you had before, but with `.add` where you have `.append`.

Comment: If you want to maintain order then a dictionary would need to used: `list(dict.fromkeys([a for b in word_list for a in b])) `